# is there a way to dowload netflix catalog?

Tags: netflix

http://api-public.netflix.com/catalog/titles/streaming 
 doesnt work anymore (it says inactive account). Is there a way to download full catalog? wanted to create app for my use.

Answer (score 1):

Netflix shut down their developer program last year, which was the only way to get the proper credentials to sign a REST request URL and download the catalog... They are not going to be issuing any new developer keys, either. So, if you don't already have one, I am afraid you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If it is saying "account inactive" you are not authenticating your call--you cannot just paste that into a browser. There is a lot of information on the Netflix developer site about this here http://developer.netflix.com/page

Comment: unfortunately I don't have a key :(.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. I'm able to begin downloading the entire catalog, but due to the size it crashes my browser.

I started reading through this link (http://developer.netflix.com/forum/read/157154) but to be honest I don't really understand it.

Anyone care to enlighten me on how to set up a request, add Accept-Encoding headers, and then parse the output? Sorry for thread highjack...

Comment: seems like you have a developer key. lucky you :). if you share your code/url, someone will help you I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, 401 for what used to work fine.  Seems to be a Netflix issue, not sure what we can do.